# installing eclipse plugin for android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-2.3, android-sdk-tools

I'm installing Android Plugin in eclipse, I'm following:

```
developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html
```

I download the adt plugin and eclipse asked me to restart, I did it and when it started I got this mistake.

[image]

I click the Open Preferences, but I can't find nothing similar to adt in my windows computer. Where should it be this folder? what is usually the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Setting Up an Existing IDE](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html) (of which the guide you are referencing is a part of):

> You should have already downloaded the [Android SDK Tools](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#ExistingIDE)

Download the SDK Tools, then set up your Eclipse ADT Plugin, directing it to the directory you installed the SDK tools into.